# how to clear _SCHEMA collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in my mongo database. in this collection, i store documents where each document has a field called `owner`. This field was of type `ParseUser` but I changed the field type to `string`so every document that is been uploaded to the collection has a `string` value and not a `ParseUser` value. I even went ahead and cleared the collection using the following command

```
db.MyCollection.remove({})
```

The problem is all my uploads to the collection fails with the error

```
schema mismatch for MyCollection.owner; expected Pointer<_User> but got String
```

I've tried

```
db._SCHEMA.remove({})
```

which fails with error

```
[js] TypeError: db._SCHEMA is undefined : @(shell):1:1
```

I've also tried the command below

```
db.runCommand({collMod: "MyCollection",validator:{$jsonSchema:{properties:{owner:{bsonType: "string"}}}}})
```

which returns

```
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

But uploads still fails with the same message.How can i clear `MyCollection` schema from `_SCHEMA` collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to access the `_SCHEMA` collection, using the command below

```
db.getCollection("_SCHEMA")
```

and everything else like deleting all rows/documents in the collection was easy

```
db.getCollection("_SCHEMA").remove({})
```